# I'm trying to get the base address of loaded dylibs in osx

Tags: c++, macos, reverse-engineering, mach-o, base-address

Well, i am trying to get the baseadresses for Loaded OSX Dylibs in running Proccesses on run time since a longtime now.

Ive dumped all attached Dylibs on runtime using dyld_all_image_infos after using task_info, got there name and ImageLoadADDRESS,mach_header and segment_command.

But i can't get there Baseaddress On runtime..

Everything works great except that i'm confused on how to get the actual Baseaddress of the requested Image in runtime! 
Also my Magic number which i got after Getting the mach_header using my imageLoadAddress is "feedfacf" . Shouldn't it be "feedface"?

After searching i found that "fileoff" in "segment_command" should lead me to the data section. This isn't working either.

My output is Looking great but when i try to view this Memory Region in Cheat engine for example it is empty!

My Debug output:

```html
mach object header
magic number feedfacf
cputype  01000007 - x86_64
subcputype 00000003
filetype 00000006
ncmds  00000015
sizeofcmds 00000988
flags  00118085
Segment
File Off 45545f5f
DYLIB: client.dylib
```

My Code is the following:

```html
               // mach_header
                mach_msg_type_number_t size4 = sizeof(mach_header);
                uint8_t* info_addr2 =
                readProcessMemory(this->task, (mach_vm_address_t) info[i].imageLoadAddress, &size4);
                
                mach_header *info2 = (mach_header*) info_addr2;

                // segment
                mach_msg_type_number_t size5 = sizeof(segment_command);
                uint8_t* info_addr3 =
                readProcessMemory(this->task, (mach_vm_address_t) info[i].imageLoadAddress + sizeof(info2), &size5);
                
                segment_command *info3 = (segment_command*) info_addr3;
                tmp_str = tmp_str.substr(tmp_str.find_last_of("/") + 1, tmp_str.length());
                //printf("%i Debug: %s\n", i, tmp_str.c_str());
                this->dylibs[cc].Name = tmp_str;
                this->dylibs[cc].imgHead = info2;
               // this->dylibs[i].tSize = this->size_of_image((mach_header*)info[i].imageLoadAddress);
                if(strcmp(tmp_str.c_str(), "client.dylib") == 0){
                    this->client = cc;
                     printf("mach object header\n");
                    printf("magic number\t%08x\n", info2->magic);
                    printf("cputype\t\t%08x - %s\n", info2->cputype,cpu_type_name(info2->cputype));//cputype_to_string(info2->filetype)
                    printf("subcputype\t%08x\n",  info2->cpusubtype);
                    printf("filetype\t%08x\n",  info2->filetype);// filetype_to_string(info2->filetype)
                    printf("ncmds\t\t%08x\n",  info2->ncmds);
                    printf("sizeofcmds\t%08x\n",  info2->sizeofcmds);
                    printf("flags\t\t%08x\n",  info2->flags);
                    printf("Segment\n");
                    printf("File Off\t%x\n", info3->fileoff );
```

could anyone may help me? 
Would appreciate it!
( p.s: Code is a bit confusing, but i am working around since days and can't get it to work, so i didn't want to write it in an Nicer style right now! )

Comment: Overchecked it and realized that my problem is just at getting the segment_command struct ! Please help!

Comment: I beleive info2 is mach_header here, so you need iterate over loading commands

```struct load_command *cmd = (struct load_command *) ((char *)info2 + sizeof(struct mach_header));
size_t k = 0;
while (k++ < info-> ncmds) {
if (cmd.cmd == LC_SEGMENT) {
  struct segment_command  *segment = (struct segment_command *)cmd;
// do something useful
}
// next load_command
cmd  = (struct load_command *)((char *)cmd + cmd. cmdsize);
}

```

Answer (score 0):

`vmaddr` field of the `segment_command` structure (or `segment_command_64` for 64-bit OS X) is address of segment in the virtual memory.

Structure of mach-o image header (dylib as particular example) is following:

| mach_header | load_command | load_command | ... | load_command |

Count of load_command structures is stored in the `ncmds` field of the `mach_header`. Some of them are `segment_command` structures, you can check it with `cmd` field of `load_command`. If `cmd` is `LC_SEGMENT` or `LC_SEGMENT_64` for 64 bit - it's `segment_command` and `segment_command_64` for 64 bit. Just cast `load_command` to the `segment_command`.

Usually, `mach_header` is stored in the first bytes of first segment of dylib. So, `info[i].imageLoadAddress` is what are you looking for if I understand your question right.

Other thing, you mentioned about magic values `feedfacf` and `feedface`. Actually, `feedface` is `MH_MAGIC`, while `feedfacf` is `MH_MAGIC_64`. All modern macbooks, iMacs and mac mini are 64 bit.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your answer !
I'm going to check your provided Information out when i am at home later that day. 

But 1 question is left right now. 
Your told me that "imageLoadAddress" should be my BaseAddress of the loaded dylib, right? 

Why is it then empty when i try to view this region in an Memory viewer? 
That's what's confusing me. 
I mean, i am in general new a t Mac Osx..
Getting the Baseaddresses of Modules was much easier on Windows!

Comment: Are you sure that you looking for memory in the right process? Look, you read a memory using your readProcessMemory function with `info[i].imageLoadAddress` address and the memory is readable, right? Otherwise you will get empty `info2`. And what do you mean with 'Memory viewer'? I don't know such tool. Link or any additional information about it will be great to understand your problem.

Comment: Yeah, i'm looking in the right Process ! 
WIth memory viewer i mean viewing the binary of this address in Cheat engine for example. I'm currently trying to test writing game cheats on osx. 
But yeah... i seem to fail at the very beginning.

Comment: Do you know about ASLR feature (Address space layout randomization)? Also, could you add `printf("memory address %08x\n", info[i].imageLoadAddress);` to your code and update output log please?